# Xcode - unexpected connection closure

Tags: xcode, icloud

I am trying to sync devices using a new app I'm developing. The sync is using iCloud. I can sync data to an iPod 4, and an iPad 3. When using an iPhone 4S, I see the activity indicator spinning, but get these repeating console messages:

```
9/29/12 10:21:02.650 AM iTunes[271]: _NotificationSocketReadCallbackGCD (thread 0x7fff79ae8180): Unexpected connection closure...
9/29/12 10:21:02.650 AM Xcode[3204]: Result for ‘/SourceCache/DTDeviceKit/DTDeviceKit-1883/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDeviceKitBase_Utilities.m’ at 783 : 0xE8000084
9/29/12 10:21:02.650 AM Xcode[3204]: _NotificationSocketReadCallbackGCD (thread 0x1152c5000): Unexpected connection closure...
```

This device does not sync.
Does anyone know what they mean? How to fix the problem? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what caused the problem, but I resolved it by using the iTunes Restore function.